# Counting ways to arrange the word REGULATIONS.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Find the number of ways the word REGULATIONS can be arranged such that
>   there are exactly $4$ letters between $R$ and $E$ .

I did

$4!\ \ \ \   \text{for}\ \ \boxed{\text{R}\color{red}{\text{_._._._}}\ \text{E}\text{_._._._._}}$

$2!\ \ \ \   \text{for}\ \ \boxed{\color{red}{\text{R}}\text{_._._._}\ \color{red}{\text{E}}\text{_._._._._}}$

$5!\ \ \ \ \   \text{for}\ \   \boxed{\text{R}\text{_._._._}\ \text{E}\color{red}{\text{_._._._._}}}$

Total=$4!2!5!$

But I am not sure if it is correct.

I look for a short and a simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: If you suppose that $R$ is the first letter and $E$ is the fifth, there is $9!$ ways to fill the rest letters. Then do the same assuming that $R$ is the second letter and $E$ is the sixth. You can continue shifting until $R$ is the sixth and $E$ is the eleventh. So there is $6 \cdot 9!$ ways to do it. Then you can do the same assuming that $E$ is the first letter and $R$ is the fifth (if $E$ could be before $R$, it is not clear could it). So there is $2\cdot 6\cdot 9!$ ways to arrange the word such way.

Answer (score 2):

Note, first of all, that E can appear before or after R, so R and E can be arranged in $2!$ ways.  Since there must be four letters between R and E, R, E, and the four letters between them form a block of length $6$.  Since there are eleven letters in REGULATIONS, the first letter in this block must appear in one of the first six positions.  For each way the letters R and E can be positioned, there are $9!$ ways of arranging the other nine letters.  Hence, the number of arrangements of REGULATIONS in which R and E are separated by four letters is 
$$6 \cdot 2! \cdot 9!$$

Answer (score 0):

R and E can be in other positions, for example:

_ _ R _ _ _ _ E _ _ _

Namely, the R can be in positions $1$ to $6$ and the position of the E is then determined. So first you have to select among these $6$ possibilities. Also, R and E can be in reverse orded, that is, the E before the R. So there are $6$ more possibilities.

Then you have to choose a position fer each reminding letter. Since there are $9$, the solution is $12\cdot9!$

Comment: The order of the R of the E relative to each other is relevant. There are two ways to order the R and the R relative to each other. Therefore, there are twice as many words as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the problem and didn't realize about order of R and E.